# DataNucleus JPA runtime enhancement with Tomcat and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jpa, datanucleus

I'm learning JavaEE by writing an application with DataNucleus as my JPA provider. I use Eclipse IDE and Apache Tomcat server for testing, and hence I'd like to set up runtime enhancement to avoid byte-compiling my classes with each test deployment.

As per [documentation](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jpa/enhancer.html#runtime), I added this to my persistence.xml file:

```
<property name="datanucleus.jpa.addClassTransformer" value="true"/>
```

However, my class does not get enhanced anyway. The error message I get is:

```
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Found Meta-Data for
class pbf.model.Message but this class is either not enhanced or you
have multiple copies of jdo-api.jar in your CLASSPATH!! Make sure all
persistable classes are enhanced before running DataNucleus and/or the
CLASSPATH is correct.
```

The docs are somewhat vague on wether Java EE requires specifying javaagent on the commandline too. If so, how do I do that with Tomcat server in Eclipse? I see no option for custom commandline and/or Java arguments when launching server.

I use datanucleus-accessplatform-jpa-rdbms v.3.3.0-release downloaded from maven repository along with all dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat is not a "real" JavaEE server AFAIK, just a servlet container, and in this situation does not implement the JavaEE server aspects of the JPA spec (i.e to use the JPA ClassTransformer that DataNucleus registered with it in your question, or create an EMF using the correct constructor etc etc). So you should use the standard Java way of using a Java agent, via the JVM command line, which is the same for any JPA implementation that supports use of agent transformers

Comment: Now Tomcat complains about NoClassDefFoundError for org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager, despite it clearly being there in a jar. Would it help if I change to, as you put it, "real" JavaEE server?

Comment: yes, so are all deps of datanucleus-core in the relevant lib folder also ? jdo-api.jar for example